# Advantage of using Jaydata with local db storage providers

Tags: sqlite, jaydata

I am curious to know the advantages of using Jaydata with sqlite instead of using sqlite only.
As I have found and experienced the difference seems is JSQL(Javascript Query Language) and its already built-in functions.
Still,I am not convinced why to opt Jaydata as everyone is using it in their applications with offline db storage providers.
Can someone kindly tell me its advantages.

Comment: Probably you should rephrase your question to get a precise answer. This one sounds like comparing datamanagement with Entity Framework vs SqlCommand/SqlDataReader objects. Please explain what do you expect in the answer

Comment: I have dited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disclaimer: I am one of the creators of JayData

JayData is an abstract data management tool that supports the same data access API over a number of different data sources, one of them is sqlite, thus letting you abstract away your data handler logic from the protocol/engine of storage.

On the client side definitely there is IndexedDB and localStore that provides a totally different API an so if you want to create an application that stores data on all HTML5 capable devices - you have to create code for all the different storage options - or you can use JayData and [save yourself from a lot of typing](http://jaydata.org/blog/write-up-to-98percent-less-code-with-jaydata).

And there is more to it: if you want to connect to large online data sources you'll need AJAX/REST as protocol layer - just for the very same things to do: create, update, delete or retrieve data. Or you can use the OData and REST adapters for JayData - to save yourself again from a huge amount of code to maintain.

Plus: neither sqlite nor IndexedDB or OData provides you with idiomatic query capabilities since it can only be implemented in the data logic layer - that is javascript bound - and is totally nondoable from an sql string point of view.

So comparing JayData to sqLite is like apples and organges.