# Datatype mismatch in Jaydata

Tags: sqlite, types, jaydata

I am managing offline db using jaydata + sqlite.
In jaydata nvarchar(20) is not a valid datatype so I need to use 'String' as datatype.
Online db is using datatype as nvarchar(20).

Now,my question is:
Is it possible to map both offline db and online db because 'nvarchar(20)' is datatype on online db and 'string' is datatype on offline db' ??

---

This is what I am supposed to create in my online db:

[image]

This is what I have created in my offline db with jaydata+sqlite:

---

```
// Table definition of  user
$data.Entity.extend("user", {
    'UserId'        :  { key:true,type:'int',nullable:false,required:true  },
    'Username'      :  { type:'string',nullable:false,required:true },
    'Password'      :  { type:'string',nullable:false,required:true},
    'UserType'      :  { type:'string',nullable:false,required:true},
    'CreatorId'     :  { type:'int',nullable:false,required:true},
    'CreatedAt'     :  { type:'datetime',nullable:true},
    'ModifierId'    :  { type:'int',nullable:true},
    'ModidiedAt'    :  { type:'datetime',nullable:true},
    'IsDeleted'     :  { type:'boolean',nullable:false,required:true}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disclaimer: I am one of the creators of JayData

You can use your online schema to create an offline database. NVarchar(20) is not even an OData type - so I guess it will just be 'Edm.String' with a maxLength=20 modifier. Edm.String is however mapped to the type "String" in JavaScript.

Sharing your schema definition would also help me giving better answers.

EDITED

The following schema definition would work with an online endpoint (provided with odata or REST) and would also create the same table definition locally.

```
$data.Entity.extend("user", {
    'userid'        :  { key:true,type:'string', maxLength:216,required:true  },
    'username'      :  { type:'string',maxLength:216, required:true },
    'password'      :  { type:'string',maxLength:64,required:true},
    ....
});
```

Is this what you needed? Please note that in JS every string is nvarchar since javascript is UTF8 internally.

Comment: Sir as you are one of the creators of Jaydata,kindly reply me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978581/advantage-of-using-jaydata-with-local-db-storage-providers too.